# Server Runtime for version v3.3.0 CE for Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am currently using Mule standalone server v3.3.0 for deploying all my ESB apps. But for developing applications using Mule Studio I am not getting the correct Server Runtime for community edition for version v3.3.0 CE.

Which version of Server Runtime I am supposed to use in my Mule studio for developing ESB applications which will be deployed on Mule standalone server 3.3.0?

Can I set my server runtime to 'MuleServer 3.4.0 CE' in my Mule Studio and deploy the ESB apps built using this on Mule standalone server 3.3.0?

Also in pom.xml of my ESB should I setting mule version as 3.3.0 or 3.4.0?

Eagerly waiting for the response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such an old runtime is available as a plug-in for the current Studio version. But there are probably old builds of Studio that have this version embedded: the best is to contact MuleSoft directly.

You definitely need to target version 3.3.0 in your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I will try to contact MuleSoft directly. Meantime if you have the dump of Mule Studio with server runtime for v3.3.0 CE for linux can you please share that dump with me.

Comment: I'll search my archives and keep you posted.

Comment: @Jai It's your lucky day: http://david.dossot.net/files/MuleStudio-CE-for-linux-32bit-1.3.0-201206220515.tar.gz